# Added Vaadin to Java Spring project in IntelliJ and getting runtime error import.meta

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea, vaadin

I have created a new project with Spring Initializr:

- Project: Gradle Project
- Language: Java
- Spring Boot: 2.7.4
- Packaging: JAR
- Java: 8
- Dependencies: Spring Boot Actuator, Spring Data JPA, Spring Web, H2 Database, PostgresSQL
  Driver, Spring Configuration Processor

When I run the application I see the following:

- Output from IntelliJ IDE indicates to go to http://127.0.0.1:64694/VAADIN/ [image]
- Next, open Chrome Browser and navigate to the URL: [image: Web page 1 of 2]
- Wait a second or two and the web page displays and just sits there: [image: Web page 1 of 3]
- After waiting for a while, look back at the output from the IDE: [image]

Getting the error:

```
2022-09-23 11:25:25.969  INFO 2916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : [vite] warning: "import.meta" is not available in the configured target environment ("es2019") and will be empty
2022-09-23 11:25:25.969  INFO 2916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : 1  |  // @ts-ignore
2022-09-23 11:25:25.969  INFO 2916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : 2  |  if (import.meta.hot) {
2022-09-23 11:25:25.969  INFO 2916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :    |      ^
2022-09-23 11:25:25.970  INFO 2916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : 3  |    // @ts-ignore
2022-09-23 11:25:25.970  INFO 2916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : 4  |    const hot = import.meta.hot;
2022-09-23 11:25:25.970  INFO 2916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : 
2022-09-23 11:25:25.970  INFO 2916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :   Plugin: vite:esbuild
2022-09-23 11:25:25.970  INFO 2916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :   File: C:/Users/krzysztof/Downloads/fundemo_v2/fundemo/frontend/generated/vite-devmode.ts
2022-09-23 11:25:25.970  INFO 2916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : [vite] warning: "import.meta" is not available in the configured target environment ("es2019") and will be empty
2022-09-23 11:25:25.970  INFO 2916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : 2  |  if (import.meta.hot) {
2022-09-23 11:25:25.970  INFO 2916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : 3  |    // @ts-ignore
2022-09-23 11:25:25.970  INFO 2916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : 4  |    const hot = import.meta.hot;
2022-09-23 11:25:25.970  INFO 2916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :    |                ^
2022-09-23 11:25:25.970  INFO 2916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : 5  |  
2022-09-23 11:25:25.970  INFO 2916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : 6  |    const isLiveReloadDisabled = () => {
2022-09-23 11:25:25.970  INFO 2916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : 
2022-09-23 11:25:25.970  INFO 2916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :   Plugin: vite:esbuild
2022-09-23 11:25:25.970  INFO 2916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :   File: C:/Users/krzysztof/Downloads/fundemo_v2/fundemo/frontend/generated/vite-devmode.ts
```

How could I get around this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to using the wrong http port instead of the default 8080: you're not indicating your Vaadin version, but if you're using the latest major (23.x or newer), you'll need to upgrade to Java 11 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

The correct URL is http://localhost:8080

The other is an internal debug url